# Margin в % внутри flex-элемента

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

Почему, когда элементу, который находится внутри flex-элемента, ставишь margin в % сам flex-элемент не расширяется, а если ставить margin в px, то flex-элемент расширяется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Процентное значение вычисляется относительно ширины родительского элемента.

Рассмотрим на примере *`inline-flex`*:

Первоначально контейнер `.div--0` имеет **Ширину** определенную контентом.
Потом от этой **Ширины** вычисляется `margin` который и добавляется `.div--1`, при этом ширина родителя не измена, т.к. есть привязка к ней.

В случаи `.div--2` пиксельное значение не привязано к родителю, что позволяет расширять родительский контейнер.

```css
.wapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.div--1 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.div--2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wapper'>
  <div class='div--0'>
    1234 5678 90
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class='wapper'>
  <div class='div--1'>
    1234 5678 90
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class='wapper'>
  <div class='div--2'>
    1234 5678 90
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чел, с display-flex поведение у них одинаковое. Я вообще не про это имел ввиду..